# What does the question mark in member access mean in C#?

Tags: c#, null, operators

Can someone please explain to me what does the question mark in the member access in the following code means?

Is it part of standard C#? I get parse errors when trying to compile this file in Xamarin Studio.

```
this.AnalyzerLoadFailed?.Invoke(this, new AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs(AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs.FailureErrorCode.NoAnalyzers, null, null));
```

[AnalyzerFileReference.cs](https://github.com/mono/roslyn/blob/master/Src/Compilers/Core/Desktop/AnalyzerFileReference.cs) line 195

Comment: It will be part of C# version 6. See http://damieng.com/blog/2013/12/09/probable-c-6-0-features-illustrated, "7. Monadic null checking"

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It is [**Null Propagation operator**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx) introduced in **C# 6**, it will call the method only if object `this.AnalyzerLoadFailed` is not null:

```
this.AnalyzerLoadFailed?.Invoke(this, new AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs(AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs.FailureErrorCode.NoAnalyzers, null, null));
```

is equal to :

```
if( this.AnalyzerLoadFailed != null)
    this.AnalyzerLoadFailed.Invoke(this, new AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs(AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs.FailureErrorCode.NoAnalyzers, null, null));
```

See [**C# 6.0 – Null Propagation Operator**](http://davefancher.com/2014/08/14/c-6-0-null-propagation-operator/) , also you can see [**here**](https://roslyn.codeplex.com/discussions/540883)

i also once wrote about this upcoming feature in c# 6 [**here**](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2014/08/null-propagating-operator-null.html)

Comment: It's bit older answer, but the above isn't correct. It's equal of the **threadsafe** version of the above code, which involves to assign the event handler to a local variable and doing the check on the local variable

Answer (score 7):

In C# version 6 it will be shorthand for

```
if (this.AnalyzerLoadFailed != null)
    this.AnalyzerLoadFailed.Invoke(this, new AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs(AnalyzerLoadFailureEventArgs.FailureErrorCode.NoAnalyzers, null, null));
```