# What does a question mark mean in C# code?

Tags: c#, operators

I've seen code like the following unrelated lines:

```
 Console.Write(myObject?.ToString());
 return isTrue ? "Valid" : "Lie";
 return myObject ?? yourObject;
 int? universalAnswer = 42;
```

There seems to be more in C#8+ like

```
 public static Delegate? Combine(params Delegate?[]? delegates)...
 string? value = "bob";
```

Are all of the usages of the question mark related or different? What do each of them mean?

Comment: @DavidG sort of... Turned out that there is no searchable answer for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43074622/question-mark-after-session-variable-reference-what-does-that-mean?noredirect=1. I'm not sure if closing as duplicate of 4 is right solution - will see in several days how search engines deal with it.

Comment: @DavidG good point - I did not notice if self-answer interface has CW option or not - changed to CW.

Comment: Long time ago there was an option to mark question/answer as community wiki. Like for `NullReferenceException` topic. Can't find this option now..

Comment: I wonder if posts should be duped to this one though?

Comment: @SergeyBerezovskiy Only answers can be marked as CW and only by the answerer or a mod. [Questions can't be done by anyone but a mod](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/67192/261748)

Comment: @DavidG I've asked this about it on Meta - https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/346099/summary-self-answer-close-as-multiple-dup-or-links.

Comment: if you guys are going to mark a question as a dup, can you provide a link to that dup?

Comment: @Gerry as links in the answer and links on top of the question not enough for you where do you expect to see those links also?

Answer (score 48):

Question marks have different meaning in C# depending on the context.

**The Null-Conditional Operator** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx), [What does the question mark in member access mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26142574/what-does-the-question-mark-in-member-access-mean-in-c))

```
Console.Write(myObject?.Items?[0].ToString());
```

**The Conditional Operator/Ternary Operator** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28.aspx), [Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator))

```
return isTrue ? "Valid" : "Lie";
```

**The Null Coalescing Operator** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173224.aspx), [What do two question marks together mean in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/446835/what-do-two-question-marks-together-mean-in-c))

```
return myObject ?? yourObject;
```

**Nullable Value Types** ([MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1t3y8s4s.aspx), [What is the purpose of a question mark after a type (for example: int? myVariable)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2690866/what-is-the-purpose-of-a-question-mark-after-a-type-for-example-int-myvariabl))

```
int? universalAnswer = 42;
```

**Nullable Reference Types**  C# 8 added nullable reference types with many more options to sprinkle question marks (it also gave new place to put explanation marks - null!" is a [null-forgiving operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-forgiving)):

Nullable string (remember that `string` is reference type behaving like value type):

```
string? value = "bob";
```

Nullable array of nullable reference objects -
[What is the ?[]? syntax in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59518973/what-is-the-syntax-in-c)

```
public static Delegate? Combine(Delegate?[]? delegates)
```

Comment: May I ask why would someone set string as `Nullable` if it can contain(?) `null` by default? Is it because of `Nullable<T>` perks/features like `.HasValue`, for example?