# What is the use of "? :"

Tags: c#

About Me: I am new to C#.

So i found this code on Microsoft!

```
int a, b, c;
a = 7;
b = a;
c = b++;
b = a + b * c;
c = a >= 100 ? b : c / 10; //This Line Is Confusing
a = (int)Math.Sqrt(b * b + c * c);
```

Can Someone explain me why the ? : are used There?

What's the use of the "? :"

Comment: Read about the ternary operator [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator)

Comment: duplicate: [What does a question mark mean in C# code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/43075113/995714)

Comment: ok thanks for the answer

Comment: Haha this is the first time I have seen this duplicate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`?:` is conditional operator in `c#`

`condition ? consequent : alternative`

> The `condition` expression must evaluate to `true` or `false`. If
> `condition` evaluates to `true`, the `consequent` expression is `evaluated`,
> and its result becomes the result of the operation. If condition
> evaluates to `false`, the `alternative` expression is evaluated, and its
> result becomes the result of the operation. Only `consequent` or
> `alternative` is evaluated.

[Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-operator#:%7E:text=The%20conditional%20operator%20%3F%3A%20%2C%20also,C%23%20Copy)